# dependent select list without reloading the jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, select

this is my code for dependent select list in jsp. It is working fine but it reloads the page to get the values in second select list. I want to do the same without reloading the jsp.
Kindly suggest.

Javascript :

```
function change(){
var cid=document.getElementById("series_id").selectedIndex;
var val = document.getElementById("series_id").options[cid].text;
window.location.replace("HomePage_new.jsp?id="+val);
}
```

jsp :

```
 <!-- Series  --> 
<tr>
<td class="password">Series</td>
<td class="password"> 
<select id="series_id" name="series_id" onChange="change()" style="color: #4B616A; background-color: #eaeced; border: 1px solid #939fa4; height: 26px; width: 120px; padding-bottom: 4px; text-align: center;">
<option value="">Select</option>
<% 

while (rs.next())
{
    System.out.println("Series loop" + rs.getString(1));


%>
    <option value=""><% rs.getString(1); %><%= rs.getString(1) %></option>
        <%

         System.out.println("Series loop" + rs.getString(1));

    }

 %>
    </select></td>
</tr>

<!-- Drawing number  -->
    <tr>
        <td class="password">Drawing Number</td>
        <td class="password"><select id="dr_no_id" name="dr_no_id"
            style="color: #4B616A; background-color: #eaeced; border: 1px solid #939fa4; height: 26px; width: 120px; padding-bottom: 4px; text-align: center;">
            <%
            rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("select DISTINCT Drawing_No from series_details where Series='"+ request.getParameter("id") + "'");
            while (rs1.next()) 
            {
            application.setAttribute("Drawing No",rs1.getString(1));
            %>
            <option value="1"><% rs1.getString("Drawing_No");%><%= rs1.getString("Drawing_No") %></option>
            <%

            }

            %>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
```

SOLVED :

Got the solution from this : 
http://www.javaquery.com/2011/07/how-to-get-value-from-database-without.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering as do not have reputation to comment.

Are you aware that the method of using JSP "inline" on the page is considered bad practice nowadays(it has been considered bad practice since the release of JSP 2.0 in 2003)?

See the latest Java EE JSP tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html

Move your business logic (what which is populating the lists) to back-end servlets.

You will then be able to display the lists without a refresh being necessary.